# Converting pandas multiple columns to dictionaries

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, dictionary

I have a pandas data frame with 100 columns and I want to create a dictionary for each column with the first column as key and I've been doing it manually.

Let me explain with a sample dataframe

`ID     a     b     c
123    jon   foo   bar
789    pan   bam   fan
278    car   bike  boat`

Let's consider the above table with column names *ID, a, b, c*. Now I am trying to create dictionaries for every column with ID being the key of the dictionary.

something like below

`dicta = {ID: a}
 dictb = {ID: b}
 dictc = {ID: c}`

What I am doing currently is:

`dicta_ = dict(zip(df['ID'], df['a']))
 dicta = {k:v for k,v in dicta_.items()}`

`dictb_ = dict(zip(df['ID'], df['b']))
 dictb = {k:v for k,v in dictb_.items()}`

`dictc_ = dict(zip(df['ID'], df['c']))
 dictc = {k:v for k,v in dictc_.items()}`

and the above code is fetching me the desired result but I have to do it manually for all the 100 columns which is not the most efficient way to do it.

I would really appreciate if I could get some help or suggestion to automate the process by writing a loop or function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: This seems like very basic functionality.  Have you gone through the Python tutorial? (https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: @thebjorn, I'd really appreciate if you can provide me an approach for the above problem if you feel its a very basic functionality. Thanks:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`set_index` then use `df.to_dict()`:

```
d = df.set_index('ID').to_dict()
```

then call the column with the value:

```
d['a']

# {123: 'jon', 278: 'car', 789: 'pan'}

d['b']

# {123: 'foo', 278: 'bike', 789: 'bam'}
```